# C# asp.net Using WebClient, is there a way to get a web page's rendered Html?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webclient

Is there a way to get the fully rendered html of a web page using WebClient instead of the page source? I'm trying to scrape some data from the page's html. My current code is like this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();            
var result = client.DownloadString("https://somepageoutthere.com/");

//using CsQuery
CQ dom = result;
var someElementHtml = dom["body > main];
```

Comment: If you are trying to scrape data from the page's html, why do you need it rendered?

Comment: What do you mean by "fully rendered html"?

Answer (score 0):

WebClient will only return the URL you requested. It will not run any javacript on the page (which runs on the client) so if javascript is changing the page DOM in any way, you will not get that through webclient.

You are better off using some other tools. Look for those that will render the HTML and javascript in the page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "fully rendered", but if you mean "with all data loaded by ajax calls", the answer is: **no, you can't**.

The data which is not present in the initial html page is loaded through javascript in the browser, and WebClient has no idea what javascript is, and cannot interpret it, only browsers do.

To get this kind of data, you need to identify these calls (if you don't know the url of the data webservice, you can use tools like Fiddler), simulate/replay them from your application, and then, if successful, get response data, and extract data from it (will be easy if data comes as json, and more tricky if it comes as html)

Answer (score -1):

better use http://html-agility-pack.net

it has all the functionality to scrap web data and having good help on the site

Comment: HTML Agility Pack is handy, but the question already implies that they're able to get the source code, and they need to execute some of the logic within the page to get additional data.